Bad request error at server side when i receive a json object
I am just making a simple axios post request to server. But I cannot understand why am I getting a bad request error. I send the data in json and i expect the data in json. But I am still getting a bad request error. Can somebody help me out ?
client side code:
const post = async (mov) => {
    
    try{
        console.log(mov)

        const res = await axios.post("http://localhost:3004/movie",{
            name: mov.name,
            yearOfRelease: mov.yearOfRelease,
            genre: mov.genre,
            leadMaleActor: mov.leadMaleActor,
            leadFemaleActor: mov.leadFemaleActor
        })

        setMyData(currentmyData => {
            return [...currentmyData,res.data]
        })

    } catch(err){
        return console.log(err.message)
    }

}

server side code:
route.post('/', async (req,res) => {
    
    const newMovie = new Movies({
        name: capitalize(req.body.name) ,
        yearOfRelease: req.body.yearOfRelease,
        genre: req.body.genre,
        leadMaleActor: req.body.leadMaleActor ,
        leadFemaleActor: req.body.leadFemaleActor
    });

    try {
        console.log("Gtrstgr")
        const movie = await Movies.create(newMovie);
        res.status(201).json(movie);
    } catch(err){ 
        res.status(400).json({message: err.message});
    }

})

The mov that I'm sending in the client side code is json parsed. I expected for the data to be posted to my database but it's just giving bad request. The exact error is:

POST http://localhost:3004/movie 400 (Bad Request)


edit your question to show us the debug you made
